# Comparing MatLab's conv2 with scipy's convolve2d

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, convolution, moving-average

I am trying to compute S3x3 moving averages, using asymmetric weights, as described in this [MatLab example](http://au.mathworks.com/help/econ/seasonal-adjustment-using-snxd7m-seasonal-filters.html#zmw57dd0e4880) and I am unsure if my interpretation of the following is correct when translating from MatLab:

1. Have I set up my matrices in the same way?
2. Does [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) do the same as MatLab's [`conv2d`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) in this instance?
3. Why is my fit so bad?!

In MatLab, the filter is given and applied as:

```
% S3x3 seasonal filter
% Symmetric weights
sW3 = [1/9;2/9;1/3;2/9;1/9];
% Asymmetric weights for end of series
aW3 = [.259 .407;.37 .407;.259 .185;.111 0];

% dat contains data - simplified adaptation from link above
ns = length(dat) ; first = 1:4 ; last = ns - 3:ns; 
trend = conv(dat, sW3, 'same');
trend(1:2) = conv2(dat(first), 1, rot90(aW3,2), 'valid');
trend(ns-1:ns) = conv2(dat(last), 1, aW3, 'valid');
```

I have interpreted this in python using my own data, I have assumed in doing so that `;` in MatLab matrices means *new row* and that a space means *new column*

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

dat = np.array([0.02360784,  0.0227628 ,  0.0386366 ,  0.03338596,  0.03141621, 0.03430469])
dat = dat.reshape(dat.shape[0], 1) # in columns

sW3 = np.array([[1/9.],[2/9.],[1/3.],[2/9.],[1/9.]])
aW3 = np.array( [[ 0.259,  0.407],
                 [ 0.37 ,  0.407],
                 [ 0.259,  0.185],
                 [ 0.111,  0.   ]])

trend = convolve2d(dat, sW3, 'same')
trend[:2] = convolve2d(dat[:2], np.rot90(aW3,2), 'same')
trend[-2:] = convolve2d(dat[-2:], np.rot90(aW3,2), 'same')
```

Plotting the data, the fit is pretty bad...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(dat, 'grey', label='raw data', linewidth=4.)
plt.plot(trend, 'b--', label = 'S3x3 trend')
plt.legend()
plt.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

[image]

It turned out that the issue was really to do with the subtle differences in MatLab's `conv2d` and scipy's `convolve2d`, from the [docs](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html):

> `C = conv2(h1,h2,A)` **first** convolves **each column** of `A` with the vector `h1` and then convolves **each row** of the result with the vector `h2`

This means that what is actually happening at the edges is incorrect in my code. It should actually be the **sum** of a the convolution of each endpoint and the relevant columns of `aW3`

e.g.

```
nwtrend = np.zeros(dat.shape)
nwtrend = convolve2d(dat, sW3, 'same')

for i in xrange(np.rot90(aW3, 2).shape[1]):
    nwtrend[i] = np.convolve(dat[i,0], np.rot90(aW3, 2)[:,i], 'same').sum()

for i in xrange(aW3.shape[1]):
    nwtrend[-i-1] = np.convolve(dat[-i-1,0], aW3[:,i], 'same').sum()
```

*To get the output above*

```
plt.plot(nwtrend, 'r', label='S3x3 new',linewidth=2.)
plt.plot(trend, 'b--', label='S3x3 old')
plt.legend(loc='lower centre')
plt.show()
```